# On Highcharts Gantt, how to display all data labels when start and end from 2 tasks overlap?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, gantt-chart, highcharts-gantt

I have 2 tasks in the same row. The labels are as below:

1. first task start
2. first task end
3. second task start
4. second task end

Label 3 is missing as it is below 2.

[image]

I'd like to have both showing, and preferably both dots separated in the same day so we can see clearly we have two tasks. One ending, another starting

Please find a working sandbox for this example: https://jsfiddle.net/Fmcg/9071Ltz6/12/

And the options:

```
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Gantt Chart with Progress Indicators'
  },
  yAxis: {
    categories: ['Magdala']
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        verticalAlign: "top",
        format: "{point.custom.label}"
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'line',
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    zones: [{
      value: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 20)
    }, {
      dashStyle: 'dot',
      value: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 25)
    }],
    data: [{
      y: 0,
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 18),
      custom: {
        label: 1
      }
    }, {
      y: 0,
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 25),
      custom: {
        label: 2
      }
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Project 1',
    type: 'line',
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    zones: [{
      value: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 28)
    }, {
      dashStyle: 'dot',
      value: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 29)
    }],
    data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 25),
      y: 0,
      custom: {
        label: 3
      }
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 29),
      y: 0,
      custom: {
        label: 4
      }
    }]
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I can actually add hours, minutes, seconds to `Date.UTC`. Therefore if task 1 ends at 1pm and task 2 starts at 4pm, it would work.

eg `Date.UTC(2014, 10, 25, 13)`